# Using haversine formula in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This test project is to demonstrate Haversine formula. It pulls latitude and longitude of international space station and calculate the distance it traveled in 0.5 seconds. However, I am unable to print value for variable dist. Any idea how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/python3

import json
import turtle
import urllib.request
from time import sleep
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

while True:
    url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    result = json.loads(response.read())
    time = result['timestamp']
    location = result['iss_position']
    lat1 = float(location['latitude'])
    lon1 = float(location['longitude'])
    sleep(.5)
    url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
    response2 = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    result2 = json.loads(response2.read())
    time2 = result2['timestamp']
    location2 = result2['iss_position']
    lat2 = float(location2['latitude'])
    lon2 = float(location2['longitude'])
    def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

        # haversine formula 
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
        r = 6371
        dist = c * r
        print ("dist:",dist)
        sleep(.5)
```

Comment: You are defining the function `haversine`, but you never call it.  Pull the definition out of the while loop, and CALL it in the while loop.

Comment: Also note that writing functions with specific tasks is a good habit, but in your program it makes more sense to compute the distance you need, `return` it and then print it in your main loop, and then wait. You don't want the function to wait before returning the value, you want to wait to avoid calling the service too often.

Comment: Thank you for the quick feedback @TimRoberts, Grismar. I'm brand new to Python, so I appreciate the help. I'll modify the code and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from @Tim Roberts and @Grismar, I modified the code and it worked. Here is the updated version

```
    def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

        # haversine formula 
        dlon = lon2 - lon1 
        dlat = lat2 - lat1 
        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
        r = 6371 
        return c * r
    hav = haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
    miles = hav*0.6213712
    print ("Distance travelled", miles)
    sleep(.5)
```